# fatal error when starting postgres on solaris

Tags: database, postgresql

I'm trying to install postgres on a sun solaris sparc instance in my home directory.

Everything is fine except when I try to start postgres server, I get the following error

```
FATAL:  "/home/reic/var/lib/pgsql/data" is not a valid data directory
DETAIL:  File "/home/reic/var/lib/pgsql/data/PG_VERSION" is missing.
```

I used the command `pg_ctl -l logfile start` to start the server.

I have followed all the necessary steps for installation on sun solaris.

Any idea as to why is this happening ?

Comment: did you initialize the data directory with initdb?  In your case something like `initdb -D /home/reic/var/lib/pgsql/data`

Comment: Yes I have done that just using initdb as I have already set the env variable PGDATA

Comment: there should be several files in the directory pointed to by PGDATA, are they actually there?  And did you run initdb as the same user that runs postgres server process?

Comment: Please add your own answer and accept it so this question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

All the necessary files are there in the `PGDATA` directory and I ran it as the same user which is trying to start the server. The problem is with the placement of env variables in the `.bashrc` instead of `.bash_profile` file. Apparently the customisations are not propagated to sub shells when the env variables are put in `.bashrc`.

My bad for not realising this! Thank you all....